# Checking if a double is equal to -0.00

Tags: c, double, comparison

I am making this big program in C, which is a part of my homework. My problem is that my program is outputing `x = -0.00` instead of `x = 0.00`. I have tried comparing like `if(x==-0.00) x=fabs(x)` but I've read that it won't work like that with doubles. So my question is are there any other ways to check if double is equal to negative zero?

Comment: How about `if(x < 0.0)`?

Comment: Checking for *exact* equality (using `==`) is seldom a good idea for floating point types, as after a couple of calculations they seldom are the exact value you compare to. Compare using an *epsilon* (and in your case check if the value is negative as well).

Comment: @FiddlingBits usually 0.00 is equal to -0.00, but our professor has specific autotests that have to be correct, and in this one the output needs to be 0.00.

Comment: @Kenan Hatibović Notice the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here.  Goal is " output needs to be 0.00", yet the question is "other ways to check if double is equal to negative zero?".  Seems to me the true question should be "how to output 0.0 when input is -0.0?"

Comment: `if(x==-0.00) x=fabs(x)` will work with `double`.  This should have "worked" for you.  Better to post a [mcve].

Comment: I'm wondering whether this particular problem should be solved with floating-point numbers at all. The two digits after the point suggest an amount of money, which is usually better represented as an integer representing the number of pennies .

Answer (score 5):

You can use the standard macro `signbit(arg)` from `math.h`. It will return nonzero value if `arg` is negative and ​0​ otherwise.

From the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/signbit.3.html):

> `signbit()` is a generic macro which can work on all real floating-
>   point types.  It returns a nonzero value if the value of x has its
>   sign bit set.
>
> This is not the same as x < 0.0, because IEEE 754 floating point
>   allows zero to be signed.  **The comparison -0.0 < 0.0 is false, but
>   signbit(-0.0) will return a nonzero value**.
>
> NaNs and infinities have a sign bit.

Also, from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/signbit):

> This macro detects the sign bit of zeroes, infinities, and NaNs. Along
>   with `copysign`, this macro is one of the only two portable ways to
>   examine the sign of a NaN.

Answer (score 4):

Very few calculations actually give you a signed negative zero. What you're probably observing is a negative value close to zero that has been truncated by your formatting choice when outputting the value.

Note that `-0.0` is defined to be equal to `0.0`, so a simple comparison to `0.0` is enough to verify a signed zero.

If you want to convert an exact signed zero `-0.0` to `0.0` then add `0.0` to it.

Comment: Likely a correct diagnosis, but then OP has the problem of making their program print “x = 0.00” instead of “x = -0.00”. That is non-trivial since a comparison to a potential rounding point, say −0.005, does not necessarily produce the same determination that `printf` or whatever they are using for formatting does (especially since it is not immediately apparent whether `-0.005` is greater or less than −0.005).

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, your program has a small negative value, not zero, which `printf` formats as “-0.00”. To print such numbers as “0.00”, you can test how `printf` will format them and replace the undesired string with the desired string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void PrintAdjusted(double x)
{
    char buffer[6];
    int result = snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%.2f", x);

    /* If snprintf produces a result other than "-0.00", including
       a result that does not fit in the buffer, use it.
       Otherwise, print "0.00".
    */
    if (sizeof buffer <= result || strcmp(buffer, "-0.00") != 0)
        printf("%.2f", x);
    else
        printf("0.00");
}
```

This is portable. Alternatives such as comparing the number to `-0.005` have portability issues, due to implementation-dependent details in floating-point formats and rounding methods in `printf`.

If you truly do want to test whether a number `x` is −0, you can use:

```
#include <math.h>
…
signbit(x) && x == 0
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two functions you need here.

First, the `signbit` function can tell you if the sign bit is set on a floating point number.  Second, the `fpclassify` function will tell you if a floating point number is some form of 0.

For example:

```
double x = 0.0;
double y = -0.0;
double a = 3;
double b = -2;
printf("x=%f, y=%f\n", x, y);
printf("x is zero: %d\n", (fpclassify(x) == FP_ZERO));
printf("y is zero: %d\n", (fpclassify(y) == FP_ZERO));
printf("a is zero: %d\n", (fpclassify(a) == FP_ZERO));
printf("b is zero: %d\n", (fpclassify(b) == FP_ZERO));
printf("x sign: %d\n", signbit(x));
printf("y sign: %d\n", signbit(y));
printf("a sign: %d\n", signbit(a));
printf("b sign: %d\n", signbit(b));
```

Output:

```
x=0.000000, y=-0.000000
x is zero: 1
y is zero: 1
a is zero: 0
b is zero: 0
x sign: 0
y sign: 1
a sign: 0
b sign: 1
```

So to check if a value is negative zero, do the following:

```
if (fpclassify(x) == FP_ZERO)) {
    if (signbit(x)) {
        printf("x is negative zero\n");
    } else {
        printf("x is positive zero\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value in using `fpclassify(x) == FP_ZERO` rather than `x == 0`?

Comment: `fpclassify` and `signbit` are macros, not function.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Maybe from the perspective of self-documentation.  Readers may not necessarily understand that `0.0 == -0.0` is true, and using `fpclassify` makes it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

To always get the non-negative version, you don't need the comparison at all.
You can take the absolute value all of the time.  If the value is non-negative, fabs should return the original value.